# GEE App: Adding a computed layer to drawingTools.layers() and plot vegetation time series plots on ui.Map

Tags: google-earth-engine, map-drawing, addlayer, drawing, button

I want to compute a buffer of 50m around the user drawn point using drawingTools. I want to save this computed buffer to drawingTools.layers() to be used later as the geometry on which my vegetation indices can be calculated and plotted on chart panels when the ui.Button is clicked.

But when I am trying to add buffer layer to `drawingTools.layers()` by the function `add()` (ie. `drawingTools.layers().add(buffer);`) it is giving an error that computed layers can not be added to `drawingTools.layers()`. What should I do?

Comment: Please share a complete minimal working example in your question body, and as a shareable code link.